# linux - mmap SHARED maximum size

Tags: c, linux, mmap

### Context

Debian 64bits.

Yesterday, I was impressed by mmap capability to create a *very* large file.
It was with the option MAP_SHARED.

In fact, I mmaped an empty 8Tb file on a 3Gb ram and 120Gb hard drive. Opening the file with LARGEFILE and using lseek64.

I know that in the end, the absolute max is the volume of data the hard drive can physically get, no matter what.

### The question

It is absolutely useless for me but, how many of those files could I create, just for fun ? I tried with 10 and it was ok. Isn't there a limit ?
ulimit displays : unlimited. Come on, nothing is unlimited.

If I put just **one char** in each of those mmap files residing on the hard drive, would the maximum be

(available disk space / (pointer to file descriptor size*4Kb))

with sizeof char == 1, and 4Kb, the real size of a file on disk ?

Thanks

Comment: To paraphrase, The way a file is kept is the directory node has a pointer to data nodes.  a data node is only allocated when the data node actually contains data.    So, in general, a huge file can be mapped, but will not actually be allocated until a node needs to contain data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the files are created with holes in them. You can do this without `mmap`. Just open a file, `ftruncate` it to whatever size you want and the operating system will most likely allow you this. The trick is that the operating system knows which parts of the file you haven't written to and will not actually allocate disk blocks for it. Reading those parts of the files will just return zeros. Unless you're on a filesystem that doesn't support that. But most filesystems on unix do.

To actually allocate all the blocks on disk for the files you'd have to write one char into each block (or group of blocks or however the filesystem does it internally, this is operating system specific). You can figure out the block size with `fstat` and experiment.

Comment: So it means that I have no limit but the physical one of the hard driven right ?

Comment: You can have a limit imposed by quota, ulimit or some other mechanism, but usually those are not set.